# Access SQL - Two Count() Statements in One?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am creating a fairly simple Access database for work and I am stuck on this one SQL statement:

I have a table that contains Handsets and the Site Ids they are assigned to. What I want to do is query the table to give me the number of `NULL` entities in one column and another column that displays the number of handsets assigned to X site id.

I can get the count of the `NULL` entities very easily but to get both results in the one statement is beyond me.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Handset_Type, COUNT(*) as "Number of null handsets"
FROM tbl_Handsets
WHERE Handset_Site_Id is Null
GROUP BY Handset_Type;
```

So now I have the count of `null` handsets but now I need the count of handsets assigned to X as well.

Something like below should be the output:

```
HANDSET     ||| NULL |||   X
handset 1   |||   50 |||   5
handset 2   |||   20 |||  10
```

Can anyone please please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Access's `IIF()` function to conditionally aggregate:

```
SELECT   handset_type,
         COUNT(IIF(handset_site_id IS NULL, 1, NULL)) AS nullcount,
         COUNT(IIF(handset_site_id = X, 1, NULL)) AS X
FROM     tbl_handsets
GROUP BY handset_type
```

Comment: Oh fantastic, thank you so so much you wouldn't believe how long I have been trying to solve this problem. i was so close to the answer but i never knew you could use the IIF function in a COUNT() ... i would have never thought of that.. once again thank you!!!

Comment: Hi is there any way to add a count from another table, my managers now want to compare this table with another table is there a way to add another column to this statement that counts in the same way for another table... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Access but this is what I usually do in MySQL

`SELECT SUM(IF(handset_site_id IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS number_of_null_handsets` ...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but i need the number of NULL and the number of X (as as in any id) in one statement

so something like

COUNT(*) handsets WHERE siteId IS NULL

COUNT(*) handsets WHERE siteId = 'x'

GROUP BY handsets

Comment: I thought I could give you the honor of finding the rest out for yourself ;) You could use two such SUM(IF(...)) selects, which would make a solution very similar to @Zane's answer. The only difference is using SUM(IF(...)) instead of COUNT(IIF(...))

Comment: Well thanks for you help anyways, i really should try and learn SQL a bit better, usually i just stick to vba but now i have been tasked to make this db application in access i need to learn it better then the standard select, insert and update statements